# INDEX on a Basic ORDER BY query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am kind of new to this whole INDEXING thing, but am loving it so far! Just a quick (possibly very easy) question...I have a very basic query, where I want to select just the 5 most recent comments from the "comments" table. The "id" column is the PRIMARY.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 19938 |       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, it is scanning the entire table...is there any way around this?

**UPDATE for SHOW CREATE TABLE comments:**

```
mysql> show create table comments;
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table     |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| comments | CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `post_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `comm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('Comment','Advice') NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `dislikes` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `datetimerss` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20091 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Look at "key" column in this table - it says "hey, I am using a PRIMARY index". MySql takes the index, orders it in descending order (but sorts the index, not the table !!!  - 19938 positions of the index), then takes 5 first id from sorted resultset, and retrieves rows from the table for these 5 index positions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there any other way around this? Or does mysql need to scan the whole table in order to find the 5 most recent?

Comment: No, MySql doesn't scan the whole table. The value "rows" in the plan is only estimate, but this is not the truth. MySql scans only the index. Your query sorts by ID, which is primary index column. So, MySql reads the index in reverse order, takes 5 positions, and reads only 5 rows from the table. Read this link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html and also thos: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: So essentially, "rows" doesn't technically mean how many rows it's scanning through? and as long as there's a "key" it should be all set?  Sorry, I am more of a PHP/Front-End guy, haha.

Comment: Could you run `show create table tablename` and post results here? I've checked on MySql and it shows me only 5 rows for the same query, could be that in your table there is a composite primary key.

Comment: Updated with what you asked for!

Comment: I've tried the query on my box, here is a link to plans: http://pastebin.ca/2427683, the plan shows only 5 rows (also shows <<filtered 70 milions rows>> in extended version), version of my MySql is 5.6, could be that plans formats differ on different version of MySql, but this query obviously uses the index and does not scan the whole table, I tested it for 70 milion rows and the running time is 0.000 second.

Comment: Alright good, thanks again!!